# How to change size of labels of x and y-axes?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How to change size of label of x and y axes?
When I left click on labels and choose position and size, I can see the options in screenshot. However I cannot change these options.[screenshot image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1obA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, double click on your diagram - a gray box will appear
   around it, you have entered the diagram editing mode.

[image: Steps 1 and 2]

2. Now click on some chart element or select its name from the
   drop-down list.
3. Click the next button on the control panel

[image: Step 3]

4. In the window that opens, change the desired settings. This window
   will be different for different parts of the diagram. Pay attention
   to the highlighted checkbox - while it is checked, the chart
   inherits the label format from the data table. If you disable it,
   you will be able to set an arbitrary format.

[image: Format Label]